# Insert Specific Cells of a CSV into MS Access table vba

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

Hi there so ive been trying to update the style of the csvs we're working with. Currently the style is unreadable for the importer so id have to write some vba to get specific cells to go into columns.

E.g Name of Company is A1

Yr1 is F25, YR2 is E25, YR3 is D25, YR4 is C25 and YR5 is B25 *These are all dates

Total Sales YR1 is F28, YR2 E28, etc. hopefully that was enough of an example.

So the vba would have to open the CSV and pick the cells based on range i imagine and then get the value and then put it into the correct column.

Hopefully that was enough to make sense of what i would like to do.
In the CSV itself there arent any column headers.

I imagined something like this

```
Dim CombLoop As Integer
Dim CSVCn As Object
Dim rsCSV As Object
Dim strSql, CombFileName, GotoRange As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set CSVCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsCVS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'CSVCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Q:\DATA\0091823.csv; Extended Properties = CSV;"

CSVCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=Q:\UPDACOS\04369248.csv;" & _
"Extended Properties= Comma delimited;"

strSql = "SELECT * FROM [a1..f75];"
rsCSV.Open strSql, CSVCn, adOpenStatic

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From dbo_UpdatedRegtemp;")

If Not (rsCSV.EOF And rsCSV.BOF) Then
    FindRecordCount = rsCSV.RecordCount
    rsCSV.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsCSV.EOF = True
        Field1 = rsCSV![A1]
        Field3 = rsCSV![A2]
        Field2 = rsCSV![A3]
        rs.AddNew
        rs![Reg# Number] = Field1
        rs![Company Name] = Field2
        rs.Update
    rsCSV.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

cSVCn.Close
Set rsCSV = Nothing
Set CSVCn = Nothing
rs.Close
```

Cheers,

Comment: Look at using `ADO` to do this.

Comment: Use _automation_. Open the Worksheet using Excel and pick the values you need, and add them to the table(s) that should hold them in Access.

Comment: Gustav were you meaning something like this: DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9,  YourTableName, YourFileName, False, "A13:C17"

Comment: that wont work because thats for spreadsheets only and this is a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Sub CSVData()
        Dim con As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        Dim currentDataFilePath As String
        Dim currentDataFileName As String
        Dim nextRow As Integer
        Dim emptystr As String
         '"H:\projectfiles\csv\", "Book.csv"
        currentDataFilePath = ("H:\projectfiles\csv\")
        currentDataFileName = ("Book.csv")
         emptystr = "NULL"


        con.Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
        'MsgBox currentDataFilePath

        con.Open

        rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & currentDataFileName & "] ", con
        rs.MoveFirst
        'nextRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        'Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(nextRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

        'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
        With rs
        Do Until .EOF

        'check the field is not null before process

         If Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
         custordernum = rs(0)
         End If

         If Not IsNull(rs(1)) Then
        ContactNAme = "" & Replace(rs(1), "'", " ")

        Else
        ContactNAme = emptystr
        End If

        If Not IsNull(rs(2)) Then
        colladd1 = "" & Replace(rs(2), "'", " ")
        Else
        colladd1 = emptystr
        End If
        MsgBox colladd1
        .MoveNext
        Loop
         End With


        rs.Close
        con.Close
        End Sub
```

Comment: the CSV fields are number indexed so you start at 0 for the first record set

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the layout there ill test it out and change it to meet my csv. Ill back to you later